# Is there any package for building app for IOS on windows?

Tags: ios, build-automation

I want to make my game engine for mobile platform (Android and IOS) and I looking for suitable packages for it. If everything is clear with the creation of a project for Android, there is a Gradle builder and SDK and NDK packages for it. But for IOS it is not clear what is needed. I searched for information but didn't find anything. For example, what does the Unreal engine use to build a project? (I dug into the files of the Unreal engine, but did not really understand anything).
I want to understand where I am not digging correctly.

P.S. I windows 10 user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at flutter sdk it is becoming very popular nowadays. You can build for android and ios with a single source base.

Comment: Can I make 3d game engine with it?

Comment: I am not sure about that you have to google for that